# Is it possible to express the following logic more succinctly using Java 8 stream constructs:

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Is it possible to express the following logic more succinctly using Java 8 stream constructs:

```
int[] gameState = {2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2};                                                                                                    
int[][] winningPositions = {{0, 1, 2}, {3, 4, 5}, {6, 7, 8}, {0, 3, 6},  
     {1, 4, 7}, {2, 5, 8}, {0, 4, 8}, {2, 4, 6}};

for (int[] winningPosition : winningPositions) {                                  

   System.out.println("RST " + gameState[winningPosition[0]] );                  

   if (gameState[winningPosition[0]] == gameState[winningPosition[1]]            
           && gameState[winningPosition[1]] == gameState[winningPosition[2]]     
           && gameState[winningPosition[0]] != 2) {                              

       // Somone has won!                                                        

       gameActive = false;

       String winner = "";                                                       

       if (activePlayer == 1) {                                                  

           winner = "Yellow";                                                    

       } else {                                                                  

           winner = "Red";                                                       

       }                                                                         
   }
```

I would like to change this code to stream.

Answer (score 1):

What about something like this?

```
Arrays.stream(winningPositions) // Stream<int[][]>
      .anyMatch(win ->  // win is an int[] array
                gameState[win[0]] == gameState[win[1]] && 
                gameState[win[1]] == gameState[win[2]] && 
                gameState[win[0]] != 2
      ); // anyMatch will stop as soon as match has been found.
```

Although it might not have any real advantages over your original approach;

Comment: Arrays.stream(winningPositions)                                              
         .filter(e -> e[0] == e[1] && e[0] == e[2] && e[0] != 2)              
         .forEach(e -> System.out.println(e[0] + " " + e[1] + " " + e[2]));   
                                                                              I need the other parr     //

Comment: // Somone has won!       
                              
     gameActive = false;      
                              
     String winner = "";      
                              
     if (activePlayer == 1) { 
                              
         winner = "Yellow";   
                              
     } else {                 
                              
         winner = "Red";      
                              
     }

Comment: I used filter what is the different betwwen filter and anymatch